# Maybe I got an old bug that I can not eject the CD-ROM tray from my laptop

Tags: xubuntu, cd, eject

Laptop:DELL inspiron 15 3521 (from 2014), BIOS version A12
OS: Xubuntu 16.04.6 , Kernel: 4.4.0-141-generic.
I tried everything I found on internet (almost all of them are old posts +- 5,6 years-old) with no success! The only way for me is to introduce a pin on CD drive hole to pull up the tray. The CD drive works, it's recognized by the system, I can play and so on. Is there a fix to this issue ? I attached a output from (sudo eject -rv) command. Appreciate some help.
["eject -rv" output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4sui.png)

Comment: Have you unmount it? Ejecting can be locked if device is busy with mount.

Comment: @LeonidMew I think so, but if I didn't unmount how to check if the device is busy with mount?

Comment: `mount` command shows all mounted devices

Comment: ok, the output of mount command is a little long, what I have to look for ? sr0 , cdrom , cd , dvd , ... I can use grep for that.

Answer (score 0):

On my system the simpliest `eject` command (without arguments) ejects DVD normally.

But with your command `eject -rv` you have specified implicit use of `-r` command and `-v` for verbose output (see [`man eject`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/eject.1.html) for details):

> **There are four different methods of ejecting, depending on whether the device is a CD-ROM, SCSI device,  removable  floppy,  or  tape.  By default eject tries all four methods in order until it succeeds.**
>   ...
>   `-v`   This makes eject run in verbose mode; more information is displayed  about  what  the command is doing.
>   ...
>    `-r`   This  option  specifies  that  the drive should be ejected using a CDROM eject command.

So your device may not support this command set.

On my system I see that `eject -s` works, it means using SCSI command set:

> `-s`   This option specifies that the drive should be ejected using SCSI commands.

---

You can also try with Gnome Disks (`gnome-disks`): find CD/DVD drive icon here, click on stop button below partitions in the right then click *Eject*:

> [image: gnome-disks]

Markings:

1. stop button with hint *Unmount selected partition*
2. eject button with hint *Eject this device*

Info:

- the *Device* field indicates that it is */dev/sr0* (for my system)
- clicking *Eject* button really eject tray, I'm running Linux kernel 4.4.0-138-generic if it matters.
- yesterday I tried the same with internal IDE DVD-RW drive and same kernel and it worked as expected.

Comment: @NOrbert it's not working, eject -s gives -> eject: unable to eject, last error: Success, and from Gnome Disks I got again an error -> Command-line eject /dev/sr0 exited with non-zero exit status 1 (udisks-error-quark, 0)

Comment: One remark : CD-ROM drive has no Disc , it's empty.

Comment: maybe I have to update and upgrade my system to see whether or not makes differences, or it's a mechanical issue.thanks